# Can't share Video to Facebook in Swift

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to share a video on facebook using FBShareDialog.

But I am getting error :

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)

I have the file path :

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8FA91DC3-D039-40DE-81BD-D70936343AD2/Documents/Erudition.mp4

And the code to share is :

```
    let fbShare  = FBSDKShareDialog.init()

    let videoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
    let shareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo.init(videoURL: path)

    videoContent.video  = shareVideo

    fbShare.shareContent = videoContent
    fbShare.delegate = self
    fbShare.show()
```

What am doing wrong here?

Comment: apparently, same situation for me.. please let me know if you know a solution.

Comment: Hey guys, did you find a solution? 

I know for sure that FBSDK wants the url file scheme to be assets-library.